# How does OpenCart access its library classes?

Tags: php, opencart

Im current trying to learn more about the core of OpenCart and how its classes actually work. Im also trying to advance my OOP skills in general as Im still learning in that area, so perhaps theres something obvious that Im not seeing.

Im wondering how a controller file knows how to find the cart class (for example).

E.g.

In catalog/controller/checkout cart there is (obviously with code removed)

```
class ControllerCheckoutCart extends Controller {
    public function index() {
      $this->cart->update();
    }

}
```

The Controller class can be found in system/engine/controller.php

`update()` can be found system/library/cart.

I assumed that in the controller.php there would be a link to the cart class, or an object made from it. (Im basing that on the use of `$this->`).

So how is the cart class actually found from the controller?

Thank you

Comment: @MarkBaker - this isn't actually the case

Comment: @MarkBaker This is incorrect answer. Autoloader is not used in OpenCart at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, your `ControllerCheckoutCart` extends the `Controller` class, so this is the class we need to focus on. You can find this class in `/system/engine/controller.php`.

Inside this class, there are two [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) we are interested in. The first is the `__construct`, where the "registry" class is loaded (found in `/system/engine/registry.php` if you're interested in picking that apart - it's very simplistic).

You can think of this as a lookup of all the classes the store uses, such as model files, library files and so on. In the construct, the registry is passed to the controller so it has a reference to it

```
public function __construct($registry) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

The second and more important magic method is the `__get` method. This is called when a classes property doesn't exist, for you to handle it yourself if you wish to do so. OpenCart uses this to try and get the class with that key from the registry

```
public function __get($key) {
    return $this->registry->get($key);
}
```

So `$this->cart` in any controller would try to get the object with the key `cart` from the registry. If you look at the `index.php` file you will see this is allocated in there

```
// Cart
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));
```

Comment: Thank you, the `__get()` function was the missing link, your post explains it well

Answer (score 0):

`ControllerCheckoutCart` *extends* `Controller`, which means it inherits all the code in `Controller` which you are not seeing here. Some code in `Controller`, likely in `Controller::__construct`, is creating the `$this->cart` object. Example:

```
class Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->cart = new Cart;
    }

}
```

Since this constructor is inherited by all child classes, they construct their own `$this->cart` as well and have access to it in their own methods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately theres nothing like that in the controller, so most likely somewhere else something like this is being declared.

Comment: Unfortunately, without the knowledge of OpenCart this is not correct. OpenCart uses some kind of *service provider* while all the services needs to be registered to the `$registry`. In a controller class when a call is done to `$cart` it bubbles up to a `Loader` that gets this registered class from the registry. Some simple implementation of IoC.

Comment: @shadyyx Yes, the specifics of how `$this->cart` comes to be will be different, surely. The main point is inheritance and whatever magic code the `Controller` contains.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jay Gilford, you need to register your newly added library class file in the **index.php** and/or **admin/index.php** (depending on if you are using it in catalog or admin)

```
$registry->set('yourlibraryclass', new YourLibraryClass());
```

so that upon system loading, Opencart knows that your class exists, then you can call all its functions by:

```
$this->yourlibraryfilename->function();
```

Please note that your library file name is normally the same as your class name, hence it is used in the example here.

After the change has been done in the index.php files, you need to logout and login again to see the changes.